# Evaluating vector::empty() is crashing the program

Tags: c++, vector, crash

I'm currently writing an extension of another program (Specificly, of a game) and i've been stuck on solving the following problem for hours now.

Any time a player (client) connects to the game server, the `OnClientConnected(int client_number);` function is called. In this function, i create an instance of a `CPlayer` class that stores player information, such as health, speed and any other data i might require. This instance, is then stored by the following class:

```
class CPlayerManager
{
    std::vector<Player*> *player_list;

    public:
    CPlayerManager();
    ~CPlayerManager();
    void AddPlayer(client_id)
    *CPlayer GetPlayerInstance(client_id);
}

CPlayerManager()
{
     player_list = new std::vector<Player*>;
}

~CPlayerManager()
{
     delete player_list;
}

void CPlayerManager::AddPlayer(client_id)
{
     CPlayer *player = new CPlayer(client_id);
     player_list->push_back(player);
}

void *CPlayerManager::GetPlayerInstance(client_id)
{
     if(player_list->empty())
     {
         return NULL;
     }

     for(std::vector<CPlayer*>::size_type i = 0; i != player_list->size(); i++)
 {
    int client = player_list->at(i)->GetClientId();
    if(client_id == client)
    {
        return player_list->at(i);
    }
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Original game functions use a client indexes as arguments and return values, so i need to obtain player instances from client indexes all the time. The problem is in the `GetPlayerInstance` function. This function might be called when NO client has been yet initialized and stored by the `CPlayerManager` instance, so we might have an empty vector.
Anytime the `GetPlayerInstance` function is called when the vector is empty, the entire game server crashes. I've been debugging a bit, and i noticed that the program crashes right in:

```
//Code reaches here
if(player_list->empty())
{
    //code does not reach here
    return NULL;
}
```

Doing `bool empty = player_list->empty())` works until i evaluate `empty` on the `if` statement.

What could be causing this strange crash?

Comment: You code won't even compile. How could it crash? http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Why so many pointers? Why not just `std::vector<Player>`?

Comment: Are you ever copying the CPlayerManager class?  If so you need to properly implement the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  Alternatively, I doubt you would actually need a `std::vector` pointer.

Comment: Don't forget about following the rule in `Player` as well. What do you have going with pointers, anyway? If you absolutely must have them, don't do dynamic allocation yourself. Just use smart pointers.

Comment: @KerrekSB, That's the first time I've heard that word used to describe code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CPlayerManager` class has no copy assignment operator or copy constructor. So if you ever copy it, deleting one instance will delete the other instance's vector, leading to disaster. (Follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).)

Really, this code should be nuked from orbit. You have no need for a pointer to a vector nor do you need a vector of pointers. Both of these things are just asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out on the right direction. I seriously apologize for writing such an horrible code but i kind of panic when i have to check if an object will be accessed outside a specific function or not. Thanks again.